# button_press signal not emitted in a subclassed DrawingArea widget

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I am creating a custom widget by subclassing a DrawingArea widget, it draws a circle in cairo. I need to get the co-ordinates of clicks on the circle. I have the following code connected to the realize signal, where I configure to receive the button press

```
static void my_custom_widget_realize_cb (GtkWidget *widget)
{   
    MyCustomWidget *mycustomwidget = MY_CUSTOM_WIDGET (widget);
    MyCustomWidgetPrivate *priv  = mycustomwidget->priv;
    GtkAllocation allocation;
    GdkWindowAttr attr;
    gint attr_mask;
    GdkWindow *parent_window;

    gtk_widget_get_allocation (widget, &allocation);

    gtk_widget_set_realized (widget, TRUE);

    attr.window_type = GDK_WINDOW_CHILD;
    attr.x           = allocation.x;
    attr.y           = allocation.y;
    attr.width       = allocation.width;
    attr.height      = allocation.height;
    attr.wclass      = GDK_INPUT_ONLY;
    attr.event_mask  = (gtk_widget_get_events (widget) |
                    GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK      |
                    GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK   |
                    GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK |
                    GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK |
                    GDK_ENTER_NOTIFY_MASK   |
                    GDK_LEAVE_NOTIFY_MASK);


    attr_mask = GDK_WA_X | GDK_WA_Y;

    parent_window = gtk_widget_get_parent_window (widget);

    gtk_widget_set_window (widget, parent_window);
    g_object_ref (parent_window);

    priv->window = gdk_window_new (parent_window, &attr, attr_mask);
    gdk_window_set_user_data (priv->window, mycustomwidget);
}
```

The overridden callback for receiving the button_press is not getting called.

Comment: you must setup a  g_signal_connect with a relevant signal, to you, when you setup up the widget.

Comment: I really do not understand what you're doing with the GdkWindows... It looks like you set the parents window as the  window of your widget but then you set priv->window to a newly constructed window? What is supposed to happen there?

Comment: @JoséFonte I have with "widget_class->button_press_event   = color_wheel_button_press_cb;" in the class init function, It's not getting called.

Comment: @jku I think it is to set the attributes on that window

Comment: @Suhas ok. So try to set the events mask differently. Use the `gtk_widget_add_events` explicitly just as a test. Something like: `gtk_widget_add_events ((GtkWidget*) self, (gint) ((GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK) | GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK));`

Comment: in the init/construct functions

Comment: Okay. The above way didn't work in the start but I had set gtk_widget_set_has_window to false. Setting it true, configuring the events mask using gtk_widget_add_events and reverting back to the default realize callback..emits the signal! I am not clear with the concept here. Have to look how to properly associate a window with a widget in the realize callback. Thanks @JoséFonte

Comment: @Suhas You must have a GdkWindow in order to have the button/motion signals, etc. Since you are subclassing a DrawingArea, it does have a GdkWindow. Good luck